# How can I write to a json file on a nginx web server using PHP?

Tags: php, html, json, nginx, webserver

I am trying to create a webpage where the user can input a username and ID and it updates a .json file with the provided input, but whenever I press the submit button, it redirects me to a blank page (i.e. example.com/index.php), and it doesn't update the JSON file.

I've tried:

- Running the website locally on my PC
- Updating example.com.conf file to run php through /var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock

I am using nginx version 1.18.0 on a Raspberry Pi 3B+

index.html, index.php and whitelist.json are all in the same directory.

HTML Code (index.html):

```
<form method="post" action="index.php">
        
<div class="group">      
    <input type="text" name="username" required>
    <span class="highlight"></span>
    <span class="bar"></span>
    <label>Username</label>
</div>
            
<div class="group">      
    <input type="text" name="uuid" required>
    <span class="highlight"></span>
    <span class="bar"></span>
    <label>UUID</label>
</div>

<button id="btn"> <p id="btnText">Submit</p> </button>

</form>
```

PHP Code (index.php):

```
<?php
$data = file_get_contents('whitelist.json');

$json_arr = json_decode($data, true);

$json_arr[] = array('uuid'=>$_POST['uuid'], 'name'=>>$_POST['username']);

file_put_contents('whitelist.json', json_encode($json_arr));
?>
```

Comment: The reason you are getting redirected after submitting the form is because inside of the form brackets you have `action="index.php"` which is sending the POST request to the `index.php` page and redirecting you. Also having two "index" files is definitely not recommended, I would only stick to one index file per dir.

Comment: When you submit a form, it redirects you to the URL in the `action` attribute. Since `index.php` doesn't produce any output, you get a blank page. `index.php` could redirect you to a different URL if you don't want to add output to it. Or you could use AJAX.

Comment: Either way, the JSON file should get updated. Check your PHP error log to see if there's a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, this `'name'=>>$_POST['username']` should be `'name'=>$_POST['username']` (You have an extra `>` )

And secondly, I would rename the `index.php` file to something else like `submit.php` so it is not conflicting (don't forget to also change `action="index.php"` to the new file name)

If you do those two things the `whitelist.json` should update with the inputted values (but you will still have the blank page problem as described by me and @Barmar in the comments)

---

**OR** instead of having two separate index's for HTML & PHP, you could just have one file `index.php`, for both (what I recommend); and then you can create your `whitelist.json` in the same directory.

**index.php Example:**

```
<?php
    # check if submit button was pressed and make sure both textboxes aren't empty
    if(isset($_POST['submit']) && !empty($_POST['uuid']) && !empty($_POST['username'])){
        
        # declare file path & name for .json file 
        $filepath = "whitelist.json";

        # check if it exists 
        if(file_exists($filepath)){
            # if it does, get contents and decode into array
            $data = file_get_contents($filepath);
            $json_arr = json_decode($data, true);
        }

        # add to existing array from above or create a new one with submitted data
        $json_arr[] = array('uuid' => $_POST['uuid'], 'name' => $_POST['username']);

        # open or create file & truncate it.
        $fopen = fopen($filepath, "w");

        # try to write data to said file; return $output regarding result
        if($b = fwrite($fopen, json_encode($json_arr, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT))) $output = "Success! ${b} bytes written to: ${filepath}";
        else $output = "Error!";

        # close open file/handle
        fclose($fopen);
    }
?>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Create ID</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h2>Create ID</h2>
        <form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input required type="text" name="uuid" placeholder="UUID"><br>
            <input required type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username">
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>

        <!-- echo $output only if declared and different than NULL -->
        <span><?php if(isset($output)) echo $output; ?></span>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: When I put the php inside of the html file, the php is shown as text on the top of the webpage. Also, the php code doesn’t change the json file whether it’s in a separate file or the html file.

Comment: @Seedname101 Because you *cannot* use PHP inside of a .html file; but, you *can* use HTML inside of a .php file. 

On top of the block of code I said: `You could also just have one file: index.php, and put all your code in there like so:`. I did forget to mention the `whitelist.json` file would need to be in the same dir as the `index.php`, But if you did move the `whitelist.json` file somewhere else; state it in the `$data` variable by adding the path. e.g. : `file_get_contents('folder1/folder2/whitelist.json')`.

Comment: I tried changing it from html to php and I updated nginx to route to the php instead, but I still doesn't update the whitelist.json file. This is exactly how my /usr/share/nginx/html/ directory looks like right now: https://github.com/Seedname101/whitelister

Comment: @Seedname101 I copied your code and tried it in XAMPP and it works for me. I updated the code yesterday on my answer, maybe try using the updated code? Really not sure why the current code wouldn't work, is PHP throwing any errors? Also i would leave `whitelist.json` blank until you add your first entry through the webpage form.

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
// router.php
if (preg_match('/\.(?:png|jpg|jpeg|gif)$/', $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"])) {
    return false;    // serve the requested resource as-is.
} else { 
    echo "<p>Welcome to PHP</p>";
}
?>
```